# Android client and server side programming

Tags: android, sockets, android-networking

I'm trying to run server side and client side examples I found on the net . 
Here's the server :

```
public class ServerActivity extends Activity {  

    private TextView serverStatus;  
    private TextView serverStatus2;  

    // DEFAULT IP  
    public static String SERVERIP = "10.100.102.15";  

    // DESIGNATE A PORT  
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;  

    private Handler handler = new Handler();  

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server);  
        serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);  
        serverStatus2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status2);  

        SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();  

        Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());  
        fst.start();  
    }  

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {  

        public void run() {  
            try {  
                if (SERVERIP != null) {  
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override  
                        public void run() {  
                            serverStatus  
                                    .setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);  
                        }  
                    });  
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);  
                    while (true) {  
                        // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS  
                        Socket client = serverSocket.accept();  
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                            @Override  
                            public void run() {  
                                serverStatus2.setText("Connected.");  
                            }  
                        });  

                        try {  
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                    new InputStreamReader(  
                                            client.getInputStream()));  
                            String line = null;  
                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                                Log.d("ServerActivity", line);  
                                handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                                    @Override  
                                    public void run() {  
                                        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO THE FRONT END  
                                        // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN BE CREATIVE  
                                    }  
                                });  
                            }  
                            break;  
                        } catch (Exception e) {  
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                                @Override  
                                public void run() {  
                                    serverStatus  
                                            .setText("Oops. Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones.");  
                                }  
                            });  
                            e.printStackTrace();  
                        }  
                    }  
                } else {  
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override  
                        public void run() {  
                            serverStatus  
                                    .setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");  
                        }  
                    });  
                }  
            } catch (final Exception e) {  
                handler.post(new Runnable() {  
                    @Override  
                    public void run() {  
                        serverStatus.setText("Error" + e.getMessage());  
                    }  
                });  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    // GETS THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PHONE'S NETWORK  
    private String getLocalIpAddress() {  
        try {  
            for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface  
                    .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {  
                NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();  
                for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf  
                        .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {  
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();  
                    if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {  
                        return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        } catch (SocketException ex) {  
            Log.e("ServerActivity", ex.toString());  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    protected void onStop() {  
        super.onStop();  
        try {  
            // MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SOCKET UPON EXITING  
            serverSocket.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  

}
```

And here's the client's code:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {  

        private EditText serverIp;  

        private Button connectPhones;  

        private String serverIpAddress = "";  

        private boolean connected = false;  

        //private Handler handler = new Handler();  

        @Override  
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_client);  

            serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);  
            connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);  
            connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);  
        }  

        private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {  

            @Override  
            public void onClick(View v) {  
                if (!connected) {  
                    serverIpserverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();  
                    if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {  
                        Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());  
                        cThread.start();  
                    }  
                }  
            }  
        };  

        public class ClientThread implements Runnable {  

            public void run() {  
                try {  
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);  
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");  
                    Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr,  
                            8080);  
                    connected = true;  
                    while (connected) {  
                        try {  
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");  
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(  
                                    new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(  
                                            socket.getOutputStream())), true);  
                            // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS  
                            out.println("Hey Server!");  
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent.");  
                        } catch (Exception e) {  
                            Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error", e);  
                        }  
                    }  
                    socket.close();  
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");  
                } catch (Exception e) {  
                    Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);  
                    connected = false;  
                }  
            }  
        }  
    }
```

When running the above on the same eclipse emulator, the server throws and exception "Socket Closed", without even reaching the while loop "while (true)". Does anybody have any idea why?

Here's the console's output:

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.example.server.ServerActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'android2.3'
Uploading server.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
Installing server.apk...
Success!
Starting activity com.example.server.ServerActivity on device emulator-5554
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.server/.ServerActivity }
------------------------------
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Performing com.example.client.ClientActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'android2.3'
Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
Starting activity com.example.client.ClientActivity on device emulator-5554
ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.client/.ClientActivity }
```

And here's the LogCat output:

```
08-08 13:04:38.165: D/ClientActivity(360): C: Connecting...
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360): C: Error
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360): java.net.ConnectException: /10.0.2.15:50907 - Connection refused
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:207)
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:705)
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:263)
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360):  at com.example.client.ClientActivity$ClientThread.run(ClientActivity.java:58)
08-08 13:04:38.176: E/ClientActivity(360):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
08-08 13:04:40.456: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(360): showStatusIcon on inactive > > > InputConnection
```

Comment: Please post the exception with the stack trace to help narrow down on where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved IT , http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html .
The problem was that android emulator instances by defaul can only interact with itself and the ethernet , so different instances can't network with each other .
If you want to do so you first have to set up a redirection in the instances .
Read this page it helps like ... A LOT :D

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 points for this:

- If you run the app on the simulator please use the IP address as your machine IP address, don't choose yourself as "10.100.102.15".
- About the port, please choose another port like 50907 or something like that (stay away from KNOWN-PORT like 8080, that usually occupied as the INTERNET port).

Try again and hope this helps.

Comment: nope it changing ports didn't help (i tried a couple including yours) , plus in onCreate() i initialize the ip with the function getLocalIpAddress(); thats implemented down the code .

Comment: Are you running both server and client on the same emulator? I guess the Server and Client are completely different apps? If so, then when you start the Client app, the Server already run this piece of code : ` @Override  
    protected void onStop() {  
        super.onStop();  
        try {  
            // MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SOCKET UPON EXITING  
            serverSocket.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  `. At this time, the socket closed, the Client cant connect to. Please run on 2 different device on same network!

Comment: it didn't help , here the process of me trying : http://postimg.org/image/bt0ulvjx7/  ,  http://postimg.org/image/55634ow4n/264b6c4c/  , http://postimg.org/image/75vj0qba7/7f470560/ ,  http://postimg.org/image/qlsfz0rj5/1d21eac1/

Comment: Well, as I see on another post, could you set your sever IP address as localhost IP address (127.0.0.1) or development machine IP address (10.0.2.2) and give it another try. Hope it works this time. Cheer bro!